# Will the implementation of RFC3465 Appropriate Byte Count in Linux 2.6.32 be affected by GRO

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

The implementation of tcp_abc in linux kernel 2.6.32 is like:

```
323     /* RFC3465: ABC
324      * We MAY increase by 2 if discovered delayed ack
325      */
326     if (sysctl_tcp_abc > 1 && tp->bytes_acked >= 2*tp->mss_cache)
327         cnt <<= 1;
```

If I understand it correctly, it can deal with delayed ack, which only has two mss aggregated at most. But when multiple ack packets are aggregated together by LRO/GRO, this implementation works poorly.

So my questions is:

1. Will tcp_abc be affected by LRO/GRO in Linux?
2. Is there any way to work around?